# All custom nifi processors stopped, missing relationships

Tags: apache-nifi

At some point in the past 24 hours every single one of my configured (and previously tested to work) custom processors stopped and started to complain that their relationships are not configured. You can see in the image however that they are configured but theyre dashed. I can fix this by just deleting the connections and reconnecting but I dont want to have to do this every time it happens. So my questions are.

What causes this? How does one fix it? I dont see anything significant in the logs.
[image]

Comment: i bet the version of your custom processor has been changed, or parameters has been changed, or something close to this... i would save current flow.xml, make change on one of processors, and compare old flow.xml to a new one - this should give you more info. or publish here diff between two xml files.